# Двойной словарь

Tags: c#, insert, словари

Подскажите пожалуйста, как заполнить такой словарь?

```
        Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, string>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < mas.GetLength(0); i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < mas.GetLength(1); j++)
                if (!dict.ContainsKey(mas[i, 0])) dict.Add(mas[i, 0], new Dictionary<int, string>() { { i, null } });
                else dict[mas[i,0], new Dictionary<int, string>() { { i, null } };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При инициализации:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, string>>
    {
        {"key", new Dictionary<int, string> {[1] = "val 1", [2] = "val 2"}}
    };
```

Добавление нового элемента:

```
dict.Add("key", new Dictionary<int, string>{[1] = "val 1", [2] = "val 2"});
```

Обращение к уже существующему ключу и добавление в него нового значения:

```
dict["key"].Add(3, "val 3");
```

---

> Как изменить значение key/value?

**Ключ** менять - плохая затея, ибо суть словаря в том, что Key имеет уникальное значение, по которому идет работа с его value. Но если хочется, то мы должны сохранить value старого ключа, удалить старый ключ и записать новое значение с новым ключом. Для упрощения можно сделать такую "приблуду" (с [En SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6499344/6808809)):

```
public static void UpdateKey<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dic, TKey fromKey, TKey toKey)
{
    TValue value = dic[fromKey];
    dic.Remove(fromKey);
    dic[toKey] = value;
}
```

Вызов:

```
dict["key"].UpdateKey(1, 2);
```

**Значение** - а вот с ним полегче и правильней будет. Код будет примерно таким:

```
dict["key"]["key 2"] = 1000;
```

Кстати! Если вы пишите value в не существующий ключ, то у вас он создастся. Это еще как один метод добавления значений в словарь.

Comment: В Вашей последней строчке, как можно написать так, чтобы если ключ уже имеется в словаре, то увеличить на единицу?

Comment: @LetsDrum Если вы про увеличение значения ключа - то это неверный подход. Ключ - это уникальное значение, а вот value - нет, его смело можем прибавлять.

Comment: Понял. Это исправил. Как я могу увеличить значения ключа второго словаря? Есть такая строчка dict[mas[i, 0]].Add(mas[i, 1], 1);

Comment: @LetsDrum Дописал ответ.